# More than one bullet cant be on screen at once?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Basically what happens is when I shoot a bullet, it creates the bullet. However, if I click again while the bullet it still on screen, it removes the bullet and makes a completely new one. So now only one bullet can be on the screen at a time. How do I fix this?
The bullet in the library has the instance name of 'bullet'

```
package
{



public class GameEnter extends MovieClip
{

    public function GameEnter()
    {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shootBullet);
    }
    public var _bullet1:bullet = new bullet;
    public var angleRadian = Math.atan2(mouseY - 300,mouseX - 300);
    public var angleDegree = angleRadian * 180 / Math.PI;
    public var speed1:int = 10;

    public function shootBullet(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        _bullet1.x = 300;
        _bullet1.y = 300;
        _bullet1.angleRadian = Math.atan2(mouseY - 300,mouseX -300);
        _bullet1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletEnterFrame);
        addChild(_bullet1);
    }
    public function bulletEnterFrame(evt:Event) 
    {
        var _bullet1 = evt.currentTarget;
        _bullet1.x += Math.cos(_bullet1.angleRadian) * speed1;
        _bullet1.y += Math.sin(_bullet1.angleRadian) * speed1;
        _bullet1.rotation = _bullet1.angleRadian*180/Math.PI;
        if (_bullet1.x < 0 || _bullet1.x > 600 || _bullet1.y < 0 || _bullet1.y > 600) 
        {
            removeChild(_bullet1);
            _bullet1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletEnterFrame);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well think about it, you store your _bullet1 variable in the class, which is fine, but every time you shoot you use the same variable and just change the x and y position again.

A better way to do this is to handle the animation for the bullet in the bullet class itself.

When you shoot, you just create a new bullet and add it to the stage.

In case you still want to use this way, it should be more like this:

```
public function shootBullet(evt:MouseEvent)
{
    var bullet:bullet = new bullet();
    bullet.x = 300;
    bullet.y = 300;
    bullet.angleRadian = Math.atan2(mouseY - 300,mouseX -300);
    bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletEnterFrame);
    addChild(bullet);
}

public function bulletEnterFrame(evt:Event) 
{
    var tmpBullet:bullet = evt.currentTarget as bullet;
    tmpBullet.x += Math.cos(_bullet1.angleRadian) * speed1;
    tmpBullet.y += Math.sin(_bullet1.angleRadian) * speed1;
    tmpBullet.rotation = _bullet1.angleRadian*180/Math.PI;
    if (tmpBullet.x < 0 || tmpBullet.x > 600 || tmpBullet.y < 0 || tmpBullet.y > 600) 
    {
        removeChild(tmpBullet);
        tmpBullet.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletEnterFrame);
    }
}
```

But the best way would be to go with option 1